# How to have an Add operation run in pre-commit or similar in Subversion

Tags: svn, hook

I have a text based wiki, which I do not want to have to remember to add files for to keep it up to date in my subversion repository on Windows 7.

I can add files from the command line, but I want to add it to the pre-commit hook (which is a batch file) so that everything from this path is added just before the commit

svn add --force E:\Path\Wiki*

The hook runs and I see other operations following this line work, but the line seems to be ignored.

What is the correct way to do what I am trying to achieve?

I guess that there should not be working path information in a hook located in the repository anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`svn info`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html) command.  One of the values that it displays is "Working Copy Root Path".  Extract that value and pass it to `svn add --force %ROOT_PATH%` to recursively add every file and folder in your working copy.